# Include Image src to LinkExtractor Scrapy CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

Im working on crawling on a site and Im using LinkExtractor from scrapy to crawl links and determine their response status.

Moreover, I also want to use the Link Extractor to get image src's from the site. I have a code and it works well with the sites urls but i cant seem to get the images. since it wont log on the console.

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [404,502]
# allowed_domains = [''mydomain']

start_urls = ['somedomain.com/']

http_user = '###'
http_pass = '#####'

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('domain.com',),canonicalize = True, unique = True), process_links='filter_links', follow = False, callback='parse_local_link'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('cdn.domain.com'),tags = ('img',),attrs=('src',),canonicalize = True, unique = True), follow = False, callback='parse_image_link'),
)

def filter_links(self,links):
    for link in

def parse_local_link(self, response):
    if response.status != 200:
        item = LinkcheckerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['link_type'] = 'local'
        item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer',None)
        yield item

def parse_image_link(self, response):
    print "Got image link"
    if response.status != 200:
        item = LinkcheckerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['link_type'] = 'img'
        item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer',None)
        yield item
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in keep using the `CrawlSpider` with    `LinkExtractor`s, just add the kwarg `deny_extensions`, i.e., replace:

```
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('cdn.domain.com'),tags = ('img',),attrs=('src',),canonicalize = True, unique = True), follow = False, callback='parse_image_link'),
```

with

```
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('cdn.domain.com'),deny_extensions=set(), tags = ('img',),attrs=('src',),canonicalize = True, unique = True), follow = False, callback='parse_image_link')
```

When this parameter is not set, it defaults to `scrapy.linkextractors.IGNORED_EXTENSIONS`, which contains jpeg, png, and other extensions. This means the link extractor avoid links found containing said extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Scarpy for over 2 years and I always use `start_requests()` method for start scraping URLs instead of `start_urls` and `LinkExtractor`

Instead of getting confused by above, simply use this

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    def start_requests(self):

        urls_to_scrape = ["abc.com", "abc.com2"]

        for url in urls_to_scrape:

            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.my_callback)


    def my_callback(self, response):

        for img in response.css("img"):

            image_here = img.css("::attr(src)").extract_first()
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I really just wanted to try out the CrawlSpider feature of scrapy. On the other hand, is there a similar way like this to get all links or hrefs from the page?

Comment: Yes, current code is scraping all img tags, you can use any selector to scrape anything from given page

Comment: Hmm do you have any idea on how I could implement callbacks to crawl all the possible urls for my site and check if there is an error?

Comment: Oh well this actually solved my problem on getting all image links from the website. Thanks!